# Invalid sidebar broadcaster specified -- What would a valid sidebar broadcaster look like?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm trying to modify the XUL School Hello World extension to Firefox so as to open a sidebar rather than a pop-up window.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get past the "Invalid sidebar broadcaster specified" error.

What would a valid sidebar broadcaster look like?

browserOverlay.js:

```
    /**
 * XULSchoolChrome namespace.
 */
if ("undefined" == typeof(XULSchoolChrome)) {
  var XULSchoolChrome = {};
};

/**
 * Controls the browser overlay for the Hello World extension.
 */
XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay = {
  /**
   * Says 'Hello' to the user.
   */
  sayHello : function(aEvent) {
    let stringBundle = document.getElementById("xulschoolhello-string-bundle");
    let message =  stringBundle.getString("xulschoolhello.greeting.label");

    // window.alert(message);
    SidebarUI.toggle("xulschoolhello-sidebar");
  }
};
```

browserOverlay.xul:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css"
  href="chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/browserOverlay.css" ?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM
  "chrome://xulschoolhello/locale/browserOverlay.dtd">

<overlay id="xulschoolhello-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/x-javascript"
    src="chrome://xulschoolhello/content/browserOverlay.js" />

  <stringbundleset id="stringbundleset">
    <stringbundle id="xulschoolhello-string-bundle"
      src="chrome://xulschoolhello/locale/browserOverlay.properties" />
  </stringbundleset>

  <menubar id="main-menubar">
    <menu id="xulschoolhello-hello-menu" label="&xulschoolhello.hello.label;"
      accesskey="&xulschoolhello.helloMenu.accesskey;"  insertafter="helpMenu">
      <menupopup>
        <menuitem id="xulschoolhello-hello-menu-item"
          label="&xulschoolhello.hello.label;"
          accesskey="&xulschoolhello.helloItem.accesskey;"
          oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.sayHello(event);" />
      </menupopup>
    </menu>
  </menubar>

  <vbox id="appmenuSecondaryPane">
    <menu id="xulschoolhello-hello-menu-2" label="&xulschoolhello.hello.label;"
      accesskey="&xulschoolhello.helloMenu.accesskey;"
      insertafter="appmenu_addons">
      <menupopup>
        <menuitem id="xulschoolhello-hello-menu-item-2"
          label="&xulschoolhello.hello.label;"
          accesskey="&xulschoolhello.helloItem.accesskey;"
          oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.sayHello(event);" />
      </menupopup>
    </menu>
  </vbox>

  <menupopup id="viewSidebarMenu">
    <menuitem id="xulschoolhello-sidebar" 
      label="&xulschoolhello.sidebar.title;"
      type="checkbox" autoCheck="false" group="sidebar"
      sidebarurl="chrome://xulschoolhello/content/sidebar.html"
      sidebartitle="&xulschoolhello.sidebar.title;"
      oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.sayHello(event);" />
  </menupopup>

  <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="xulschoolhello-hello-world-button"
      class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional" 
      label="&xulschoolhello.hello.label;"
      tooltiptext="&xulschoolhello.hello.tooltip;"
      oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.sayHello(event);" />
    <!-- More buttons here. -->
  </toolbarpalette>

  <broadcasterset id="MainBroadcasterSet">
    <broadcaster id="hello-sidebar"
        sidebarurl="chrome://xulschoolhello/content/sidebar.html"
        sidebartitle="Hello world!"
        group="sdiebar" />
  </broadcasterset>
</overlay>
```

Obviously there are a couple more files as laid out in the XUL School Hello World example.

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial or your source code files?

Comment: @Kashif:  The section of the tutorial using a pop-up window rather than a sidebar is here:  [The_Essentials_of_an_Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/The_Essentials_of_an_Extension), sidebars come into play here:  [Adding_sidebars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Adding_sidebars).

Comment: The [Getting_Started_with_Firefox_Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Getting_Started_with_Firefox_Extensions) section provides an [install link](https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/5139/=xulschoolhello1.xpi) to the .XPI archive for the pop-up window version.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error message could be found by looking at the [SidebarUtil.toggle() source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-sidebar.js#193). `SidebarUI` could not find a `broadcaster` having id `xulschoolhello-sidebar`.

You need to change

```
SidebarUI.toggle("xulschoolhello-sidebar");
```

to

```
SidebarUI.toggle("hello-sidebar");
```

Also there is a typo in xul file. I believe `group="sdiebar"` should be `group="sidebar"`

NB: If you are learning XUL for creating firefox extensions, I would highly suggest to look at [Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK). The XUL based API would be soon deprecated.